# Is there a way to work with files from a dictionary with similar names in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

So, I was wondering if there could be a way to use files from a dictionary with similar names in a loop,

I have this dictionaries:

```
dcm = {}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'DCM_hydra*.txt'):
       dcm[filename[:11]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(dcm)

#OUT_INPUT
out={}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'Out_hydra*.txt'):
       out[filename[:11]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(out) 
#MATRIX_INPUT 
mtr={}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'matrizr_hydra*.txt'):
       mtr[filename[:15]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(mtr)
```

The names I get from each one of these dictionaries are the same except for a number
 (for example:`DCM_hydra01, DCM_hydra02, DCM_hydra03` etc.)

Then I need to use these files from the dictionaries in some functions:

```
IFOV1= gi.IFOV_generic(out['Out_hydra01'],mtr['matrizr_hydra01'], dcm['DCM_hydra01'],endpoint)
IFOV2= gi.IFOV_generic(out['Out_hydra02'],mtr['matrizr_hydra02'], dcm['DCM_hydra02'],endpoint)
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to write a loop that would let me get these **IFOV** functions without the need of writing them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterate over dicts by `zip()` function like example bellow. It gives you list with all functions for all files. But don't forget than len of all dicts should be equals

```
dcm = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
out = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
mtr = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}

IFOV = []

for d, o, m in zip(dcm, out, mtr):
    IFOV.append(
        gi.IFOV_generic(out[o], mtr[m], dcm[d], endpoint)
    )
```